# Is finding a very large clique NP-hard?

Tags: graph-theory, approximation-hardness, clique, independent-set

We know that, unless P=NP, for any $\epsilon$ we can't distinguish in polynomial time between the two cases:

1. There exists a clique of size at least $n^{1-\epsilon}$
2. All cliques have size at most $n^\epsilon$

I'm interested in distinguishing between the following two cases:

1. There exists a clique of size at least $n - n^{\epsilon}$, $\epsilon < 1$
2. All cliques have size at most $c \cdot n$, $c < 1$

Is anything known about this (or similar) problem? I would actually expect this to be in P, but I seem to find counter-examples for simple algorithms I try to apply (e.g. trying to grow the clique one vertex at a time breaks if we randomly remove some fraction of edges outside of the clique).

I'll be very happy if the problem is hard for some fixed $\epsilon$ and $c$.

Comment: Let $k$ be the minimum number such that there exists a clique of size $n-k$. Now, $k$ is the equivalent to the minimum vertex cover of the complement, so it can be 2-approximated in polynomial time.

Comment: Thank you very much!